# Seaborn Scatterplot not ignoring zero values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

Boolean selection has been used to select only `['Premium', 'Good']` from `cut`, and `['D', 'F', 'J']` from `color`. However, all of the categories of `cut` are shown in the legend.

1. Why are all the `cut` values showing in the legend?
2. How can this be implement to only show the values actually in `diamonds`?

```py
import seaborn as sns

diamonds = sns.load_dataset('diamonds')

diamonds = diamonds[
            diamonds.cut.isin(['Premium', 'Good']) & 
            diamonds.color.isin(['D', 'F', 'J'])
            ]
diamonds = diamonds.sample(n=100, random_state=22)

# plot
sns.scatterplot(x='carat', y='price', hue='cut',data=diamonds);
```

[image: Here cuts which have been excluded are also present]

Comment: It's only plotting Premium and Good, but because the column is loaded as Categorical it is seeing all of the categories. look at `diamonds.cut.unique()`

Comment: Add the `hue_order=` parameter to the plot call: `sns.scatterplot(x='carat', y='price', hue='cut', hue_order=['Premium', 'Good'], data=diamonds)`.

Comment: I did that initially and it works too but I wanted an easier method, this is too time consuming because when using hue I'll have to assign hue order and when using style I'll have assign style order, is there not an easier way?

Comment: It's been this way for a long time. Note the date of the duplicate. You can use `hue_order=diamonds.cut.unique()`, but you will have to specify `hue_order=`.

Comment: ```hue_order=diamonds.cut.unique()```, this works fine, thanks.

Comment: if i use ```diamonds = pd.read_csv('DiamondData.csv')``` instead of ```sns.load_dataset('diamonds')``` , there is no need for ```hue_order=diamonds.cut.unique()```, its works just fine without it.

Comment: Yes, that's true. This is only an issue if a column is Categorical from sns.load_dataset, or from using pd.Categorical on a column, which is kind of what I said in the first comment. But you seem to have it resolved, so good.